# Pick random but unique array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project in which I need to create a simple html page questionnaire for work. Its been more that 8 years I have not done any programming. Now suddenly be given a project. Stack Overflow helped me in getting through most of the project. But now I have hit a wall.

I need to pick a random but NO repeated question from array of questions. I am using JavaScript to display the questions and  using this code example as basis for project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Quiz</title>
<style>

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0, randomq=0;


var questions = [
  ["What is 36 + 42", "64", "78", "76", "B"],
  ["What is 7 x 4?", "21", "27", "28", "C"],
  ["What is 16 / 4?", "4", "6", "3", "A"],
  ["What is 8 x 12?", "88", "112", "96", "C"]
  ];

function get(x){
  return document.getElementById(x);

}


function renderQuestion(){
  test = get("test");


  if(pos >= questions.length){
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
    get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed";

    // resets the variable to allow users to restart the test
    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;

    // stops rest of renderQuestion function running when test is completed
    return false;
  }
```

// shuffle questions

```
  random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (questions.length)) ;
   get("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;


  question = questions[random1][0];
  chA = questions[random1][1];
  chB = questions[random1][2];
  chC = questions[random1][3];
  test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
  // the += appends to the data we started on the line above
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
  // use getElementsByName because we have an array which it will loop through
  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
    if(choices[i].checked){
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }
  // checks if answer matches the correct choice
  if(choice == questions[random1][4]){
    //each time there is a correct answer this value increases
    correct++;
  }
  // changes position of which character user is on
 pos++;
 // then the renderQuestion function runs again to go to next question
  renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for a way that there is no repeated questions.

Please advice...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shuffle the array once, then `.splice()` out the questions until the array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help.

i have found the solution with : fisher-yate shuffle

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack would be to create a boolean array whose size would equal to the number of questions. Initialize all values to false.

Then select a random question, and set the corresponding boolean value to true, if it's false. If it's true, that means it has been used before, so skip the question and move one until all values are true.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just splice out the used questions?

questionArr.splice(index, 1):

Or if you want to keep the used questions save them in a usedQuestions array and do 
questionArr = [...usedQuestions];
usedQuestions = [];
When the questionArr is empty